# In the anime, what happens to Akame after the fall of the empire?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

At the end of the anime adaptation of *Akame ga Kill!*,

> everyone died,

but what happened to Akame?

They mentioned her needing to get out of the country because the people would call for her execution due to her time as an imperial assassin, but did she get out, or was she caught? If she escaped, where did she go?

Comment: I'm not sure how the manga ends, but maybe some clarification to wether you refer to the manga or the anime adaptation would help, as I'm pretty sure the anime had an original ending.

Comment: I was referring to the anime, but I'm well aware that they strayed from the manga.

Comment: in that case it'd be all open to speculation, since the anime is its own timeline, I tried to find interviews with the staff but none of the ones I found really went into what happens with Akame after the ending, I guess they just left her fate open-ended. I don't think any developments in the manga would mean anything to the anime ending since by the end it was an original work by the studio.

Answer (score 4):

**What happened to Akame?**
I only read the manga but as paulnamida mentioned, if you want anime-only events about Akame's whereabouts, you are out of luck since all you get is a [post-credits scene](http://akamegakill.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_24) which does not even mention specifics as to where she is exactly:

> 'In a post-credits scene, Akame wanders in a desert, ambushed by several people who appear to be Teigu users. She again states that as a survivor, she shoulders the feelings of her deceased comrades, and begins battle with the group of bandits.'

This doesn't tell really tell much. **Did she get out, or was she caught? If she escaped where did she go?** As mentioned above, she was not caught but as to where she went or where she was headed to during the post-credits scene, no one knows.